# How can I make a home widget behave like a launcher icon?

Tags: android

I have a widget that acts as a launcher on the home screen.
How can I make it behave like a launcher icon?

I use this layout for portrait:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <RelativeLayout
    android:background="@drawable/widget_background_selector"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_width="74dip"
    android:layout_height="79dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dip">

    <ImageView android:id="@android:id/background"
      android:layout_width="72dip"
      android:layout_height="72dip"
      android:layout_marginLeft="1dip"
      android:layout_marginTop="4dip" />

  </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the background selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/widget_background_pressed" /> 
  <item android:state_window_focused="true" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/widget_background_focused" /> 
  <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" /> 
</selector>
```

This way if I use the DPAD the widget is focusable but the click doesn't work.
The touch still works but the widget is not displayed as focused.

Any idea what I do wrong?

Comment: To detect a click did you override onTouch or onClick?

Comment: The RemoteViews provides only the setOnClickPendingIntent method.
What methods are you referring to? From which class?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but have you tried setting `android:focusableInTouchMode` to true?

Comment: I tried that too ... but nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the code that registers your click events? Can you show that?

I don't see any id attribute for your RelativeLayout, so my stab is that you haven't even registered an OnClickPendingIntent for the RelativeLayout for which you want to handle click events. And perhaps you *have* created an intent for the ImageView, which is receiving the touch events, but not the dpad click events, because it's parent (the RelativeLayout) has requested focus (and has no click event-handler).

Comment: I found what was the problem a week ago, but I forgot to close this question.
It was related to the missing ID as you noticed. :-)